# Linking Google cloud sql instance django website to google domain

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have created django website on Google cloud and its running on sql instance (https://school-website-272007.el.r.appspot.com).
I already have a google domain, and i want to link this to it.

I followed as below:

1. Created a VM instance on GCP and linked the external ip to my running sql instance.
2. Created Zone and 'A' / 'CNAME' in the Cloud DNS section.
3. Added the new DNS settings to Google domain - DNS settings under custom.

(used https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart and other youtube links to perform)

But still my google domain is not able to link to the website (https://school-website-272007.el.r.appspot.com)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [App Engine Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains). With custom domains you can add the domain you may want to redirect to your App Engine app instead of using the `appspot` link.

While configuring the custom domain, it will tell you which DNS records you have to add to your DNS.

Comment: I have updated as mentioned in the link, i have wait for a day to reflect.

Do you think, i should remove everything i have done previously ?

Comment: Thanks FerVelvet, I have removed all the process i did earlier, can just followed your links. It works.